# Unable to Process INR Payments in PayPal Sandbox Mode - Currency Not Supported

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am currently working on integrating PayPal Sandbox mode into my application for processing payments in Indian Rupees (INR). However, I am encountering an issue where the currency is not supported, resulting in a 400 Bad Request error.

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have already attempted to enable the "Allow payments sent to me in a currency I do not hold" option and set it to "Allow and convert to US Dollars" in the payment preferences. Despite this configuration, the INR currency is still not supported.

Is there any additional setting or configuration required to enable INR currency support in PayPal Sandbox mode? I need to ensure that my application can process payments in INR successfully.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to ensure that my application can process payments in INR successfully.

Then you need to use a different payment provider, one that supports domestic INR payment in India.

PayPal does not process domestic payments in India. Only international payments in [a PayPal supported currency](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/reference/currency-codes/) (INR is not one of them).